# Associating a function in Emacs after looking up the code with M-x describe-key

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to associate the following function (which toggles on and off full-screen on the active buffer):

```
(defun toggle-maximize-buffer () "Maximize buffer"
  (interactive)
  (if (= 1 (length (window-list)))
    (jump-to-register '_)
    (progn
      (set-register '_ (list (current-window-configuration)))
      (delete-other-windows))))
```

with the keyboard shortcut `Alt+Sfhit+o`.

When I look up the Emacs code for this shortcut with `M-x describe-key`, I get
`ESC O-` in the minibuffer, but when I add the following line on my `.emacs` config file it doesn't work

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<ESC O>") 'toggle-maximize-buffer)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4016914/1030675

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the syntax of the [`kbd`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Sequences.html) macro wrong. `<ESC O>` would be for a key called `ESC O` (with a space; Emacs key names don't contain spaces). For the two-key sequence `ESC` then `O`, use `ESC O` or equivalently `M-O`.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "ESC O") 'toggle-maximize-buffer)
```